# How to you label (caption) the table title? (for example:Tests of Between-Subjects Effects for One-way ANOVA)

Tags: anova, multilabel, labeling

How do you lable/caption a table under One-way ANOVA?

```
Tests of Between-Subjects Effects for One-way ANOVA
```

OR

```
Tests of Between-Subjects Effects of One-way ANOVA
```

[image]

Two-way ANOVA's table:

1. Levene's test of equality of error variances
2. Tests of normality
3. Between Subjects factors
4. Descriptive statistics
5. Tests of between-subjects effects
6. Estimated marginal Means

One-way ANOVA's table:

1. Levene's test of equality of error variances
2. Tests of normality
3. Tests of between-subjects effects
4. Multiple Comparisons of Post Hoc Tests (Tukey HSD)

How we going to different between the tables for One-way ANOVA and two-way ANOVA as both lable the same?

Thanks.

Comment: can someone help?